# Ember-Data parent template not updating when model is changed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using EAK with a simple nested routing structure, but changing the parent model in the child controller does not change the top-level view. For example if I have the following router.js file:

```
this.resource('similar', function() {
    this.resource('list', { path: '/list/:phone_id' });
    this.resource('upload');
    this.resource('new');
});
```

For the 'similar' route model I am using ember-data together with the RESTAdapter which is backed Flask.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('phone');
    }
});
```

If I manipulate the model inside the 'upload' controller then the changes are not reflected in the template, e.g.

```
var record = this.store.createRecord('phone', {
    numbers: [1,2,3,4]
});

record.save();
```

will not change "{{#each list in model}} {{list.numbers}} {{/each}}".
If I reload the page it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the REST endpoint did not return the new record (with the id attribute set).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `store.find` which hits the server and stores that exact list, try using `store.filter`. `store.filter` "remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created locally"

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter